# Problems with a ZipFile.OpenRead()

Tags: c#, .net, zip, windows-phone-8.1, c#-ziparchive

I use the Microsoft Compression library and i need method for unzip files, and this is my code:

```
    public async void unZipFiles()
    {
        //Declaration of variables
        var classSync = new Sync();
        StorageFile ZipArchive = await        ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ZipFile.zip");
        var pathToExtract = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.ToString();

        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(ZipArchive.Path.ToString()))  //ERROR HERE!!
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(pathToExtract, entry.FullName));
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

And when my compiler arrive in this code line:
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(ZipArchive.Path.ToString()))

Give me this error:

[image]

And can Open my zip... Any ideas?

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-and-extract-zip-a4794b24

Comment: could you translate what is written in the screen shot ?

Comment: what's the value of `ZipArchive.Path` ?

Comment: Hi all,
This is my path: ZipArchive.Path = "C:\\Data\\Users\\DefApps\\APPDATA\\Local\\Packages\\48553385-7bda-46b0-8125-1a3172d838f0_vjpmpwzahfhma\\LocalState\\sincrofit.zip"
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: And the error is this:
Attempt by security... the other lines say that exeption type, and the last one say that if u have a controller for this exeption u can continue to debug...

Comment: You cannot use those classes and methods from Windows Phone. See the link in my first comment for example code on how to do it.